# How do stop my iTunes songs from skipping?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have 2G's of RAM on IBM T42 XP Pro. I have tried everything from re-installing iTunes, resetting speakers and Quicktime and various other solutions offered by other forums but to no avail. Everything was doing alright until I installed the last two new versions. Now I can't listen to iTunes without it skipping, like a bad CD. HELP!!

Comment: What is the version number you've installed giving you problems?

Comment: I updated to 10.2.1..........The songs play well on my Blackberry, no problems.

Comment: The songs also play on my iPod without any skips.

Answer (score 0):

I have traced similar problems to drivers for both video and sound.

You may wish to try updating your video card and sound (card or integrated) drivers to see if it helps, but be sure to keep a copy of the drivers you are currently using.

If you may have recently updated drivers, consider trying an older version.